# Bad request on facebook page wall post (getResponse())

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, .net-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I get an error code 400 "Bad request" when I try to post to a page wall. Here's the code:

```
public string Post(Int64 Id)
{

    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var msg = (from t1 in db.Table1
                   join t2 in db.Table2 on t1.UserId equals t2.UserId
                   where t1.Id == Id
                   select new {t1, t2}).FirstOrDefault();

        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + msg.t2.Table3.FBPageId + "/feed";
        AppendQueryString(ref url, "access_token", msg.t2.Table3.FacebookAuth);
        AppendQueryString(ref url, "privacy", "{\"value\": \"EVERYONE\"}");
        AppendQueryString(ref url, "message", msg.t1.Message);
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
        webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        System.IO.Stream os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        os.Close();

        try
        {
            var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Stacktrace;
        }

    return "Something random";             
}
```

The code ends at the return in catch (`webRequest.GetResponse();` failed).

`AppendQueryString` is just a method that generates the query string (? or &) and returns the new `url`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to split up the "base" url and the parameters into two, and put the parameters into `byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);` and keep the url in `var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);`

Works now